# define dynamic width of textbox using DOM approach

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, textbox, width

i am tyring to insert textboxes to create empty rows but i want first textbox should be of 50px only
i am creating them onclick event of a button using DOM approach
how to define the width with respect to following approach

j is a variable being handled somewhere & cols is no: of columns to be created

```
for(var t=1;t<=cols;t=t+1)
            {

                var cell = row.insertCell(t);
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.type = "text";
                element.id=   'text['+j+']['+(t)+']';
                element.name= 'text['+j+']['+(t)+']';
                element.value="";

                cell.appendChild(element);
            }
```

Comment: i tried following too but not worked
 if(t===1)
                {
                    element.style.width="50px";
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some times it may works

```
element.style.width = width + 'px';
```

try it once in case the above suggestions fails

or by using this,

```
element.setAttribute("style","width:50px");
```

Comment: thnx...
this worked

element.setAttribute("style","width:50px");

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In CSS:

```
.firsttext
{
    width: 50px;
}
```

In Javascript:

```
if (t==1)
{
    element.className = "firsttext";
}
```